# pass two parameter in routing in angular 6

Tags: angular

i am passing two parameter with route but its not working.
when i click on routerLink it is redirecting me to my default route.
means there is no route who is accepting parameters.
What am i missing..?
THANKS in Advance.

paht is:

```
{path:'Buy/:term1/:term2', component: Buycomponent}
```

and i am passing parameters like this:

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/Buy',{term1:'sale',term2:'home'}]">data</a>
```

in component i am getting parameters like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(response => console.log(response.term1 , responce.term2));
```

.
Updated...

for single value it is working fine.

```
{path:'Buy/:term1, component: Buycomponent}
```

and passing parameter like this:

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/Buy','sale']">data</a>
```

in component i am getting parameters like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(response => console.log(response.term1));
```

Comment: You could access the route like `<a [routerLink] ="/Buy/sale/home">data</a>`

Comment: The way you are doing, it is called query parameters. What you want do is route parameters. Which, people have already answered

Comment: @IvanS95 thanks for answer but its not working for me

Comment: @SumeetKale did you find any thing wrong in my code..?

Comment: @IvanS95 That doesn't work. You either bind to an expression or use a string value, not both.

Comment: @IngoBürk can you explan..?

Comment: It can be `routerLink="./some/path"` or `[routerLink]="someExpression"`, but not `[routerLink]="./some/path"`. It *can* be `[routerLink]="'./some/path'"` (note the extra `''`), but that's a bit pointless.

Comment: @IngoBürk yeah, my bad, forgot about the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/Buy','sale','home']">data</a>
```

Use this syntax when you want to pass optional parameters

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/Buy',{term1:'sale',term2:'home'}]">data</a>
```

Comment: it  works after some tries i don't know why it was not working on first try..anyway its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/Buy','sale','home']">data</a>
```